# Why jmeter recording does not capture Basic Authorization related Http headers

Tags: java, node.js, jmeter, integration-testing, superagent

I am using JMeter Proxy to record my integration tests being run via node.js with superagent & superagent-proxy. The tests record initially under the listener and show accurate and expected results, requests, and responses. But, my problem lies in the fact that for some reason not all of the scripts being recorded in the recording controller are capturing all of the HTTP headers correctly. Namely, I am setting an 'Authorization' header in some of my superagent tests that come across fine in the test script recorder, but once they are turned into scripts under the recording controller the 'Authorization' header doesn't show up. When I run these tests from the controller they fail with a 401, since they don't have the 'Authorization' header like the ones being run from superagent to the proxy server.

Any ideas on what could be going wrong here?

EDIT: It appears to be capturing custom headers, but not the authorization one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a regular behaviour of JMeter  Test Script Recorder, it removes:

- Cookie header
- Authorization header

In order to setup Basic Authorization, add to your plan [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager)

Using HttpClient4 set in bin/hc.parameters:

```
http.authentication.preemptive$Boolean=true
```

And add in user.properties:

```
hc.parameters.file=<full path to hc.parameters>
```